# Convert CSV to XML using Mule 4

Tags: xml, csv, mule, dataweave, mule4

Facing issues while converting CSV to XML using dataweave 2.0 in mule 4.

input payload (CSV):

```
employee_id,amount  
12345,75  
67890,15  
13579,38
```

Output Result (XML):

```
<ch:Data xmlns:ch="xxx:com.abcdef.report">
  <ch:Entry>
     <ch:Employee_ID>12345</ch:Employee_ID>
     <ch:Cost>75</ch:Cost>
  </ch:Entry>
  <ch:Entry>
     <ch:Employee_ID>67890</ch:Employee_ID>
     <ch:Cost>15</ch:Cost>
  </ch:Entry>
  <ch:Entry>
     <ch:Employee_ID>13579</ch:Employee_ID>
     <ch:Cost>38</ch:Cost>
  </ch:Entry>
</ch:Data>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [dynamic object feature](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-types#dynamic_elements) so that it expands the array in the parent object

```
%dw 2.0
ns ch xxx:com.abcdef.report
output application/xml
---
ch#Data: {
    (payload map {
        ch#Entry: {
            ch#Employee_ID: $.employee_id,
            ch#Cost: $.amount 
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Am getting below error while using this code 

"\"You called the function 'map' with these arguments: \n  1: Binary (\"employee_id,amount\\r\\n12345,75\\r\\n56432,15\\r\\n67890,5\\r\\n\" as Binary {encodi...)\n  2: Function (($:Any, $$:Any) -> ???)\n\nBut it expects arguments of these types:\n  1: Array\n  2: Function\n\n\n 6| \t(payload map {\n  |  ...\n11| \t})\n\nTrace:\n  at map (line: 6, column: 3)\n  at main (line: 6, column: 11), while writing Xml at \n 6| \t(payload map {\n  |  ...\n11| \t})\n.\n\n 6| \t(payload map {\n  |  ...\n11| \t})\n\nTrace:\n  at main (line: 6, column: 3)\"

Comment: This is because your payload doesn't have the mimeType set. Where are you getting your payload from?

Comment: Changing MIME type to application/csv for input payload worked. Thank you @Machaval

Comment: I'm glad to help